# How to add HTML elements into email templates in WooCommerce?

Tags: email, woocommerce

I've seen many articles about `WooCommerce` email customization, but I can't find any that explains how to actually modify the page structure of the emails. For my project I need to add new page elements containing text and images. I want to actually build my emails as I would build a page.

Echoing stuff in email templates doesn't seem to work though. If I take `templates/emails/customer-completed-order.php`, echo things in it then preview the result using [Email Log plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/email-log/installation/), it doesn't make any difference: my `echos` don't render.

Are WooCommerce emails actually impossible to customize in depth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Woocommerce emails can be customized but only to certain extent.

Content of any single email are strucuted in a little complicated manner.

E.g. The header part of the email is rendered from file `email-header.php`. Footer part of the email is rendered from file `email-footer.php`. Again for each different type of there are different template files, such as `customer-invoice.php`, `customer-new-account.php`, `customer-processing-order.php` etc. Contents of the emails are also called from different hooks and functions. Again all the email elements are embeded with inline styles. These styles are defined in yeat another file `email-styles.php`. Strange you can't easily find reference of this file in any of the email templates.

Regarding adding additional content/information in the emails should be possible.

Answer (score 2):

**Go to this folder:**

```
plugin/WooCommerce/template/emails
```

copy the folder `emails` to your theme folder then modify php files in `emails`folder

If your change not actually work check this article:

https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/

also some plugin available for create custom Email template

Comment: Thanks but the problem isn't related to template override. Even when modifying core WC templates (for the sake of experience) it doesn't work. As for plugins I only found http://codecanyon.net/item/email-customizer-for-woocommerce/8654473 which doesn't allow to do what I want.

Comment: The files should be in `your-theme/woocommerce/emails` unless your theme has modified the `woocommerce` folder to be named something else. 1. you need to try sending real emails and not relying on a preview plugin (which just proposes another point of failure) and 2. you need to ensure that you do not have [template debug mode](http://scottbasgaard.com/woocommerce-2-1-please-debug-template-overrides/) enabled.

Answer (score -1):

In theme `functions.php`, please create a two hook to add new content or apply HTML tags:

```
 function add_order_email_instructions( $order, $sent_to_admin )
  {
       $order_id = $order->get_id();
      if(!$sent_to_admin) 
       {
         //Your message or code
       }
      else
       {
          //Your message or code
       }
    }
   add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'add_order_email_instructions', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'new_order_reply_to_admin_header', 20, 3 );
function new_order_reply_to_admin_header( $header, $email_id, $order ) 
{

    if ( $email_id === 'new_order' ){
        $email = new WC_Email($email_id);
        $header = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $header = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    }
    return $header;
}
```